# PHP DatePeriod does not return duplicate hours during DST change?

Tags: php, datetime

I am looping over a series of hours using DatePeriod. This works for periods not containing DST changes. It works for a missing hour during switch to DST. But it does NOT work for a double hour during switch to non-DST season.

Base code:

```
$zone   = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');
$start  = new DateTime('2016-01-01', $zone);
$end    = new DateTime('2016-01-02', $zone);
$int    = new DateInterval('PT1H');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $int, $end);
foreach($period as $point)
    echo $point->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
```

This gives:

```
2016-01-01 00:00
2016-01-01 01:00
2016-01-01 02:00
...
2016-01-01 23:00
```

For $start = '2016-03-27' and $end = '2016-03-28' it gives:

```
2016-03-27 00:00
2016-03-27 01:00
2016-03-27 03:00
....
```

This is expected because 02:00 does not exist that day.
But for $start = '2016-10-30' and $end = '2016-10-31' it does not work:

```
2016-10-30 00:00
2016-10-30 01:00
2016-10-30 02:00
2016-10-30 03:00
....
```

We expect a double hour. It is not there. Outputting the timestamps using $point->format('U') shows that the timestamps are correct and there is a jump of 7200 seconds between 1 and 2 o'clock instead of the expected 3600.

Why does PHP not follow my specified interval of 1 hour? How can I get the period to include this hour? I have tried $int = 'PT60M' and similar, but that does not change anything.